# How to start an application

Tags: java, excel, spring

Hy guys, I am relatively new to programming, since now I've been learning the basics so sorry if my question seems stupid.
I want to make a desktop application that allows a user to authenticate and to complete a formular and press a send button. Than what he entered in that formular i want to be inserted in an excel file that already exists. It is possible to do this just in java, or do I have to use spring? For the record I am using net Beans as IDE. 
 I know that are similar questions about exporting in excel but the other answers are to advanced for me and I need to start from bellow

Comment: This can be a tricky thing to accomplish, even for those who are experienced in Java. You should start with something simpler

Comment: So Spring is not Java then?

Comment: Inserting anything into an Excel spreadsheet from Java isn't trivial (at least for newbies).  Agree with ControlAltDel -- start with the basics and work up to it.   It's a fine goal, but get ready for some frustration if you want to use MS proprietary artifacts in a non-MS development environment.

Comment: Welcome to the fascinating world of programming. One of the first things you'll need to learn is to decompose big problems into atomic parts. SO is not the right place to ask broad questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little broad, but I think it's clear enough what technologies you need to use here.

You say it's a desktop application, so you'll need a windowing toolkit. Swing is a popular choice in Java, but there are others. Look at [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits#Based_on_Java) and select one that you think fits your needs. You asked if you need Spring, and the answer to that is definitely no. Spring is for making web applications. You're looking to make a desktop application.

The authentication part you mention is peculiar - what are you authenticating against? This may require a network call, or including a library that performs the authentication.

Entering the formula should be pretty straightforward, you just need a text input from your windowing toolkit.

Adding that formula to a spreadsheet in Java would most likely be done through a library called POI. You'll need to add POI to your classpath (if you're using eclipse that's pretty easy.) You would need to find the sheet, row, and cell to put the formula in, and set the formula text to whatever you captured with your text input from the last step.

Each of these steps is simple to follow when broken down, and each is probably large enough to warrant its own StackOverflow question, which you should do if you run into trouble. Can't really help you select a windowing toolkit, because there's a lot of options and really only you know the criteria you're looking for.

Comment: I want to make a formular like this dog-checbox,  cat-checbox. The user just clicks the checbox he wants and then press Send and in the excel under the cat cell it is entered 1. I want to make a list of users, a vector I think, hardcoded. And when a user enters a formular his name is also entered in a cell in the excel file.

Comment: Those are all examples of just capturing the text and sending them to the excel file in the last step. Focus on each of the steps one at a time. First, get a windowing toolkit and get your base app. Then add your authentication. Then add your data capture. Then add your excel export. One step at a time.

Answer (score -2):

You absolutely do not (and probably **should not**) need to use Spring just to start a simple Java application. Simply create a main method inside a class:

```
public class MyMainClass{
   public static void main(String... args){
      System.out.println("I'm started!");
   }
}
```

And then compile and run that class either via the command line or from the IDE of your choice.

Comment: OP doesn't seem to mean "start" *this* literally.

Comment: @kryger I disagree. But then again we're both just trying to guess without any real information.